# Computer occasionally shuts off mid-boot ; and other weird power issues

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure, power

So I have a desktop computer I assembled myself back in July. It works great and I didn't encounter any hardware issues, except for some weird power ones.

When my computer is on, everything is fine. No problem, no random shut-down, no lack of wattage or anything like this.

The problems are when it's off. Occasionnaly, when trying to switch it on, the computer would shut down mid-boot without any appparent reason. If I try to restart it, same thing. The only way I can get it to work is by entering the BIOS and exiting it, after what everything would work fine.

Note that this doesn't happen everytime I switch my PC on. It just happens randomly.

Now for the other minor problems.

I think my PC is never completely off until I switch the PSU off, this for some reasons :

- My motherboard has decorative LEDs that are always on, even when I switch the PC off. However, if I switch the PSU off and on again, these LEDs turn off and don't turn on again - untill I press power button.
- If I put the PC in hibernate mode (which, correct me if I'm wrong, is just switching the PC off but keeping a save of its current state on the hard drive), and I press a key on the keyboard, the keyboard LEDs switch on. Strangely enough, this doesn't happen with my mouse - which has LEDs too.
- Sometimes, but more rarely though, I experience the same keyboard issue when the PC is off.
- If I plug in a xBox 360 controller when the PC is off, its LEDs would light for half a second and then stop. Unplug, replug : same thing.

So as I'm not an hardware expert (I'm more into software actually), I can't seem to find out whether all these strange behaviours are related and, be they or not, where they could come from.

My specs are as follows :

- Windows 10 Pro N 64 bits
- LEPA MX F1 650W PSU
- Intel Core i7-4790K @ 4.0 GHz CPU (no overclock)
- 8Go HyperX Fury DDR3 RAM
- Asus Z97-E 1150 motherboard
- Sapphire Radeon RX480 GPU
- Kingston 240Go SSD used for C:\
- Seagate Barracuda 1To HDD used for D:\

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT** :
So thanks to @HighTechGeek's comment I was able to resolve the main issue (shut down mid-boot), that was caused by Fast Boot (the great part is that with my SSD, I didn't notice any change in speed while turning my PC on).

For the motherboard never being off, I found my anwser [There](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?52422-HOW-TO-Turning-off-All-motherboar-lights-when-shut-down-Keep-ROG-LED-when-PC-is-on).

Comment: Disable Windows 10 Fast Startup, hybernate, sleep and hybrid sleep. Use your motherboard's built in RAM diagnostics or create a USB or CD of MemTest86 and check for bad RAM. Some motherboards provide continuous power to some USB ports for charging devices while the system is off. Check your motherboard docs and BIOS settings

Comment: Thank you very much, fast boot was actually the problem !